# Does panel in JLayeredPane change if it is editted after being added to the JLayeredPane?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlayeredpane

After adding a JPanel to a JLayeredPane using

```
layeredPane.add(panel);
```

After adding this if we change the panel does the panel in the JLayeredPane also change?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Objects are passed by reference in Java, so any changes you make will effect it.

You may have to repaint the panel after making changes, in order to get it to show up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

> After adding this if we change the panel does the panel in the 
>       JLayeredPane also change?

Yes is possible, but visible only by calling

```
layeredPane.add(panel);
layeredPane.revalidate();
layeredPane.repaint();
```

Comment: Why do you use code formatting for quotes that should be prefixed with `>`?  Also `reapaint()` - is that home improvement by the Grim Reaper? ;)